# Multiple geocode API calls and really slow code

Tags: javascript, php, google-api, geocoding

I have to find distance between pickup and business address as well as delivery and business address.

I did the php code by calling geocode api to get address coordinates with dynamic address input from database. It then calculates the required distances (solves the purpose) but it results in multiple api calls due to 1000s of business registered as it loops through all of them.

I tried curl instead file_get_contents too but it doesnt make any difference.
Can we decrease the api calls and make it faster .

```
                /* this whole code is in loop for all businesses*/
                /*address from database*/
                $raddress=$rstreetno." ".$rstreetname.",".$rsuburb.",".$address_state.",".$rpostcode;
                $mapsApiKey= get_option('shipme_radius_maps_api_key');
                /* API Call*/
                $urllocal = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".urlencode($raddress)."&sensor=false&key=".$mapsApiKey;
                $result_string = file_get_contents($urllocal);
                $result = json_decode($result_string, true);
                if(!empty($result['results'])){
                    $remoaddLat = $result['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
                    $remoaddlng = $result['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];
                }
                $earthRadius = 6378;//earth radius in kms.
                $latpickFrom = deg2rad($jobpickup_lat);
                  $lonpickFrom = deg2rad($jobpickup_lng);
                  $lataddress=deg2rad($remoaddLat);
                  $lngaddress=deg2rad($remoaddlng);
                  $latdelTo = deg2rad($jobdelivery_lat);
                  $londelTo = deg2rad($jobdelivery_lng);

                  $latDeltapickup = $lataddress- $latpickFrom;
                  $lonDeltapickup = $lngaddress - $lonpickFrom;
                  $latDeltadel =  $latdelTo - $lataddress;
                  $lonDeltadel =  $londelTo - $lngaddress;
                  $latjobdist = $latdelTo - $latpickFrom;
                  $lonjobdist = $londelTo - $lonpickFrom;

                    /*Distance between business address and pickup*/
                    $a = sin($latDeltapickup / 2) * sin($latDeltapickup / 2) +
                    cos($lataddress) * cos($latpickFrom) *
                    sin($lonDeltapickup / 2) * sin($lonDeltapickup / 2);
                    $c = 2 * asin(sqrt($a));
                    $distancefrompickup = round($earthRadius * $c,2);

                    /*Distance between business address and delivery*/
                    $a1 = sin($latDeltadel / 2) * sin($latDeltadel / 2) +
                    cos($lataddress) * cos($latdelTo) *
                    sin($lonDeltadel / 2) * sin($lonDeltadel / 2);
                    $c1 = 2 * asin(sqrt($a1));
                    $distancefromdel = round($earthRadius * $c1,2); 

                 /*Distance between pickup and delivery*/

                $a2 = sin($latjobdist / 2) * sin($latjobdist / 2) +
                    cos($latpickFrom) * cos($latdelTo) *
                    sin($lonjobdist / 2) * sin($lonjobdist / 2);
                    $c2 = 2 * asin(sqrt($a2));
                    $jobdistance = round($earthRadius * $c2,2);
```

/* Then these distances are used in further comparisons*/

Comment: Do a bulk reverse geocode and store results in db then you can use geospacial search in db

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: Hey charlietfl , So you recommend doing geosoacial search in db rather calling API multiple times , is it much faster ? I havent tried before but I will give it a go . Thanks.

Comment: Hi DalmTo , The code works fine but gives geocode error due to lots of API calls considering the whole code in loop for all the users in database. It is super slow too while showing the results which annoys the end users. I want to avoid the multiple API calls.